Is ::ng-deep officially un-deprecated since Angular v18
As per the documentation of Angular v18, I can't find a deprecation note for ::ng-deep. Does that mean it's un-deprecated and could be used again? Or it still has to be phased out from legacy code?

The Angular team removed any mention of deprecation in the v18 docs but kept an important note:

The Angular team strongly discourages new use of ::ng-deep. These APIs remain exclusively for backwards compatibility.

The context of this undeprecation is that there are no alternatives the basic usecase of overriding inner-styles. Back in the way, when the feature was deprecated, it was expected to be replace by a browser feature but that feature never landed, hence the un-deprecation.
Also note that ::ng-deep enables overriding styles but it is assumed to be at the same level as using a private API. Styles & classes often aren't part of public API contracts. This is why Angular Material for example moved toward design tokens to enable customization via a public api.

Yes, it is officially undeprecated since February 2024: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/54219
However, it is worth to note that the Angular team strongly discourages using it in new code, as per docs.
